# Why does starting a session cause my function-generated form value to change when submitted?

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form, and use PHP to set the value of one of its fields by creating and echoing a hash. I'm not sure why, but when I submit the form without calling `session_start()` my `$_POST` variable shows the correct hash that was embedded in my HTML when the page first loaded. Starting a session causes the hash to change when the form is submitted, almost as if the hash function is being called again.

This sort of makes sense to me, but this was not always happening; I haven't changed my code, and previously tested this functionality.

I'm using `XAMPP` to test my program on my local server, and compare the echoed hash with the "view page source" command in my browser, looking at the hash that was generated before clicking the submit button.

```
<?php 

// Toggle this to see different results
// session_start();

function generateRandomToken() {
    return md5(uniqid());
}

if (isset($_POST['token'])) {
    echo $_POST['token'];
}

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo generateRandomToken(); ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: define `generateRandomToken()` after `if (isset($_POST['token'])) { ... }`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Running this code in a new browser appears to fix the issue. Why would that matter? Another user mentioned the page being cached.

Comment: Starting a session doesn't change the submitted data. If you load the page, check the token value in the form by checking "inspect element" in your browsers dev-tools and then submit the form, do you really get a new token or the token you just saw in the form before the submit?

Comment: If the page would be cached, you would keep getting the same token over and over. Are you getting the same token?

Comment: No, a different token is generated every time. It's quite clearly different.

Comment: Please edit your question and include in detail, step by step, how you're debugging this. How are you comparing the values?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm not sure what to say, other than that my problem appears to have been resolved by clearing my cache (CTRL + F5) in my original browser, or by trying my code in a new browser. Very odd behavior, but now printing `$_POST['token']` shows the token that was embedded in the HTML.

The fact that this bug appeared out of nowhere, with absolutely no changes whatsoever (and I mean absolute; I never changed my code, nor even opened the associated page files for days) leads me to think it has something to do with my browser.

Comment: I should mention that I've been using Brave browser, and had caching issues with `CSS` as well. I have no idea if my problem was truly due to the browser, but Brave does not seem as development-friendly as Chrome or IE.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form, page get refreshed, and new token generated. If you want to use same token even after page refresh save a token value in session if it's previously not set.

```
function generateRandomToken() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && !empty($_SESSION['token'])
      $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    else{  
      $token = md5(uniqid());
      $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    }
    return $token;
}
```

Once form processed successfully unset session variable. I hope this will help.

```
unset($_SESSION['token']);
```